# What is the consistency strength of this addition on simple type-set theory?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, foundations, type-theory

Language: multi-sorted first order logic with equality and membership, where for each natural $n$ there is a set $x^n$ of sort $n$. Equality "$=$" only occurs between variables of the same sort, and set membership "$\in$" can only be written with the variable on the right having one sort higher than the variable on the left.

**Axioms:**

**Extensionality:** $\\\forall z^n (z^n \in x^{n+1} \iff z^n \in y^{n+1}) \implies x^{n+1}=y^{n+1}$

**Comprehension:** $\exists x^{n+1} \forall y^n (y^n \in x^{n+1} \iff \varphi(y^n)) $

**Infinity:** $\{x^0 \mid x^0=x^0\} \text { is infinite}$

**Choice:** $\{x^n \mid x^n=x^n\} \text { is well-orderable }$

Where $n=0,1,2,...$; $\varphi(y^n)$ is a typed-formula in which "$y^n$" is free but not "$x^{n+1}$" ; and "$\text{infinite}$" is after Dedekind's.

This theory is $\sf TST + Infinity + Choice$, it is equi-consistent with MacLane set theory.

Now suppose we've added an axiom stating that the bottom tier (i.e. $\{x^0 \mid x^0=x^0\}$) is **uncountable**, and **regular** with respect to every well ordering on it, and add that if a set $x^n$ is strictly smaller than the bottom tier then the set  $\{y^n \mid y^n \subseteq x^n\}^{n+1}$ is strictly smaller than the bottom tier also.

> Now, what would be the consistency strength of the resulting theory with respect to $\sf ZFC$?

To be noted is that this theory doesn't have an untyped powerset axiom! So unreachability by powering is not all that obvious here, well to me at least.